# If the encryption algorithm broken or analysed, can an attacker find my password?

Tags: encryption, attacks

If the encryption algorithm broken or analysed, can the attacker know what my password was?

Comment: The question seems very vague.  What is the exact scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the rules upon which cryptography is based is that everything must be supposed known to the attacker. The only thing that is secret is the key. Some famous algorithms which follow this principle are DES, AES and RSA. So an attacker can't find your password only by studying the encryption algorithm.

Comment: does the password encrypted with the same algorithm or with anther one.?

Comment: @rezx are you talking about a specific algorithm?

Comment: sure AES if someone analyze it will he know what is my password, and is that possible to analyze algorithm and become useless.?

Comment: @rezx It's not possible to find out the key, knowing how AES works, in a short amount of time. Of course, having a theoretically infinite amount of time, one can always crack an algorithm by a brute-force attack. But the fact is that doing so is usually a problem computationally speaking: in order to crack AES (especially with 192- and 256-bit keys) you need an enormous amount of time. Thus, finding out the key becomes practically unfeasible.

Comment: i know that if i use the full key 64 for the password ( letter,number...) it will be
96^64 = 7334304125596190624668832643061791071911921761558623296040973972480495126634460976537700765146565217101386328744001668808441856 possibility. and even the fastest computer on the planet cant dont it in a year, but there is other ways than brute-force, right

Comment: another thing is analyze the algorithm mean brute-force the key, cant they know how the algorithm work and reverse it, cuz i read the they broke 9 rounds of the AES?

Comment: @rezx Until now, all other proposed attacks against AES have been proved not to work, as far as I know, or they simply lower the computational complexity needed to crack it, but to a point where it basically still remains unfeasible to do. If you use a 128 bit key, some more techniques can work.

Comment: @rezx there are some attacks which are more efficient than brute-force attacks with a low number of iterations (6). That's why you use 10, 12 or 14 iterations usually. With such a number of iteration, brute-force remains the only possible thing to do (until now).

Comment: by iterations u mean rounds right, so with 6 rounds they can break it, but how can they reverse it and back to the plain text, and if they can broke 6 rounds they can break more, whats the difference made by 10~14 rounds

Comment: @rezx yes, by iterations I mean rounds. You can reverse it for example by intercepting several encrypted messages and trying to decrypt them with all possible keys until you have a plain text that has some sense. More rounds means more complexity, these attacks probably work only on 6 iterations because they exploit some vulnerability which is eliminated using more rounds.

Comment: @rezx oh, before I forget, if you are worried by an attacker finding your password, you must remember that another step to keep into consideration is key generation and key exchange (Diffie-Hellman). This is another way in which an attacker can find the key.

Comment: ok, last question,, DES is broken is it only for the short key that could found by brute-force attack, or there is another thing.?

Comment: @rezx DES was insecure mainly because of the length of the key, yes, 128 bits is not enough. Other types of attack with a lower complexity of a brute-force attack were also discovered (an example is differential cryptanalysis).

Comment: @ user, thanks alot for ur help and time, about accepted the answer when i try it say " Vote Up requires 15 reputation ", byt i made a feedback any way :)

Comment: @rezx that is the vote up feature, accepting an answer is different: you simply need to click on the checkmark under my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a principle in security called the [Kerckhoff's Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), which most modern things in security follow, including cryptographic algorithms. Essentially it means that systems should not rely on secret algorithms, but rather secret keys. One of the big reasons for this is that keys are really easy to change if compromised, but this is not so with algorithms. In general, "[security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)" is frowned upon in security, and certainly major crypto systems don't derive their security from obscurity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
but there is other ways than brute-force, right
```

The only weakness to AES is a brute force attack.  There are no other ways to compromise it at this time.  Please understand AES can still be weak if they key is not long enough.

256 and 512 are the suggest key lengths.  The only way to decrypt AES encrypted data is to know all the information.

```
If the encryption algorithm broken or analysed, can the attacker know what my password was?
```

If an algorithm is broken, then it should not be used, because its well broken.

The AES algorithm has been analysed, it has been determined by people smart then you and most people even on this website, that its also secure.

An algorithm must be secure, it has to be determined that its strong enough, not to fall apart because some simple trivial error like WPA for instance.